# Can't using StructureMap 4.5.2 in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap, structuremap4

I'm new to StructureMap and i'm using version 4.5.2. I registered my DataContext with StructureMap in Global.asax like this:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetupIcoContainer();

        // Code that runs on application startup
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    private void SetupIcoContainer()
    {
        var container = new StructureMap.Container(_ =>
        {
            _.For<Data.IUnitOfWork>().Singleton().Use(x => new Data.Database.DataContext());
        });
    }
```

and I'm using the dependency in my repository class like this:

```
var uow = new StructureMap.Container().GetInstance<Data.IUnitOfWork>();
```

but i get this error:

> No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'Data.IUnitOfWork'

The `Data.IUnitOfWork`, `Data.Database.DataContext` and my Repository class are in another assembly. The StructureMap doesn't register the DataContext.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var uow = new StructureMap.Container();
```

instantiates a new empty container that does not know IUnitOfWork.

You can try to set a global static variable in global.asax.cs

The best way is to use StructureMap as MVC DependencyResolver

Here there is a way
[How to get the Structuremap IContainer instance from Asp.Net MVC 5 Dependency Resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095491/how-to-get-the-structuremap-icontainer-instance-from-asp-net-mvc-5-dependency-re)